# Add another UIPickerView to UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have an existing Viewcontroller with 2 UIPickerviews. Now I want to add another UIPickerview with another variable. How to do this?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var pickerview1: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerview2: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerview3: UIPickerView!

var reps = ["1 x","2 x","3 x","4 x","5 x","6 x","7 x","8 x","9 x","10 x","11 x","12 x","13 x","14 x","15 x","16 x","17 x","18 x","19 x","20 x","21 x","22 x","23 x","24 x","25 x"]

var weight = [["0","1","2","3","4","5"],
            ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],
            ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],[","],
            ["0","25","5","75"],["kg","lbs"]]

var exercises = [["A","B","C"],["X","Y","Z"]]


func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return ((pickerView == pickerview2) ? reps.count : weight.count)

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return ((pickerView == pickerview2) ? 1 : weight[component].count)

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

    return ((pickerView == pickerview2) ? reps[component] : weight[component][row])

}
```

The third UIPickerview should show the variable exercises in the Viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a switch statement

For example:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    switch pickerView {
    case pickerview1:
        return reps.count
    case pickerview2:
        return weights.count
    case pickerview3:
        return exercises.count
    default:
        assertionFailure("Unknown pickerView")
    }
}
```

Side Note: I've matched your variable names, but I think you should make your pickerView variable names camelCase, i.e. pickerView1 instead of pickerview1.

Comment: Thanks a lot but there's an error occurring "Missing return in a function expected to return "Int" ". I don't quite understand.

Comment: Oh sorry, try adding an assertionFailure() in the default case instead of "break", which should take care of the compile error. I've updated the code.